# gson Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 64 path $.data

Tags: android, json, gson, pojo

> I have an JSON In following format.

```
{
    "data":{
             "list1":[],
             "list2":[],
             "list3":[]
           }
}
```

> Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 64 path
>   $.data error my gson model is

```
public class Model{
    private DataBean data;

    public DataBean getData() {
    return data;
}

public void setData(DataBean data) {
    this.data = data;
}

public static class DataBean {

     private List<list1> list1;
     private List<list2> list2;
     private List<list3> list3;

     public List<list1> getList1() {
                        return list1;
                        }

     public void setList1(List<list1> list1) {
                        this.list1 = list1;
    }

     public List<list2> getList2() {
        return list2;
    }

    public void setList2(List<list2> list2) {
        this.list2 = list2;
    }
..
}

}
```

My Concern is regarding the GSON. It's expecting Object in place of Array Where am i going wrong?

Comment: Can you please post DataBean class as well. All the ArrayLists should be inside DataBean class only.

Comment: `list1`, `list2`, and `list3` are class names?

Comment: @VinitThaker yes I Have edited

Comment: Try following Java naming conventions. Classnames should be capitalized and Gson may be confusing the variable name with the class name